# obj.Attributes(0) returns "ID", obj.getAttribute("ID") returns nothing

Tags: excel, msxml2, vba

This is my first attempt to use `MSXML2.DOMDocument` within VBA, and I'm having a "huh?" moment right off the start. My document looks like this...

```
<Locations>
    <Location ID="23456">
        <Properties>
            <Property ID="12345">
etc.
```

I want to make a report with all the Location IDs, so I:

```
Set locs= XDoc.SelectNodes("//Location")
For Each loc In locs
     Debug.Print loc.Attributes(0).Text
Next
```

and I got `23456`. Yay! But of course, those attributes might move around, so let's fix that...

```
     Debug.Print loc.getAttribute("ID").Text
```

That returns `Object required`. Looking in the debugger, I can see that `loc` has one attribute and it's `name` is `ID`. That seems right. I can also see that loc.getAttribute("ID") returns null. That seems wrong.

So what's going on here?

Comment: Try this `Debug.Print loc.getAttribute("ID")`. It should fix the issue.

Comment: @SIM - that worked and I'll upvote if you make it an answer. But WHY does this work? is it "if it says get then this returns text" sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VBA at all but my guess would be that the .attributes[] property returns an attribute object (XmlAttribute?), which would let you access its identifier and value, whereas the getAttribute() function is the getter for the text value of the attribute with that identifier.